# Excel 2010 replacing WEBSERVICE() with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that converts USD into EURO.

I designed it with Excel 2013 and I use the new function WEBSERVICE to retrieve historical exchange rates from internet, API here:

http://api.fixer.io/2017-01-07?base=USD&symbols=EUR

And my formula look like below:

```
=IF(OFFSET(INDIRECT("R[0]C",),0,-2)<>"",SUBSTITUTE(MID(WEBSERVICE("http://api.fixer.io/"&TEXT(EOMONTH(OFFSET(INDIRECT("R[0]C",),0,-2),0),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"?base=USD&symbols=CNY"),50,6),"}",""),"")
```

Explain:
If the second cell to the left of the current cell is not empty, then fill it with the web data. The parameter in the formula is the month end date, also calculated by a cell in this table.

The table has multiple rows, and this is working perfectly for us, only problem is that some users are still on Excel 2010 or older, is there a way of doing this in VBA?

Comment: There is a way to do this in VBA, but it will take you some research. Look at IE automation, web parsing / web scraping and see what you can knock up. Happy to help you out once you have something to work with.

Comment: Thanks @Glitch_Doctor, I can get vba to do one cell, but I don't know how to get all cells automatically. I know PHP but VBA is not my back yard.

Comment: Ah I see, that would be by using a loop and a counter. quite a bit of work but I see you got a sweet UDF from @AxelRichter that is much better than going through the pain of all that.

Comment: Hi @Glitch_Doctor, thanks for your  help anyway. Yes Axel Richter did provide a very good solution, I only need to tweak my forms a little bit and all should work seamlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest version of a VBA `WEBSERVICE` equivalent would be:

```
Public Function myWEBSERVICE(strURL As String) As String
 Dim oWinHttp As Object

 Set oWinHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

 oWinHttp.Open "GET", strURL, False
 oWinHttp.send ""

 myWEBSERVICE = oWinHttp.ResponseText

End Function
```

Used as UDF (User Defined Function) as a cell formula like:

```
=mywebservice("http://api.fixer.io/"&TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"?base=USD&symbols=CNY")
```

where `A1`contains a date.

For a reference see [responseText Property (IXMLHTTPRequest)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Examples there are in JScript and must be converted to VBA.

Comment: Thank you @Axel Richter, just tried your solution in Excel and it says "The formula contains unrecognized text", and give a #NAME? in the cell. I'm on Windows 10 with Office 2013 FYI.

Comment: The function needs to be placed within a default VBA Module.

Comment: you are a star! Working perfectly!